# Undefined Method 'Published'

Tags: ruby

I just started learning Ruby on Rails and got stamped on Chapter 7 of Beginning Rails 4 Third Edition Page 151.

I generated controller as follows;
$rails generate controller ControllerName [actions] [options]. This one worked OK but when I tried to generate a controller for the Users
$rails generate controller Users. I got the following error message.

> /routing/mapper.rb:328:in check_part : Missing :controller key on routes definition, please check your routes.  (ArgumentErroe).

This is what my routes look like

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'controller_name/[actions]'

  get 'controller_name/[options]'

  root :to => "articles#index"
  resources :articles
  root :to => 'users#show'

end
```

I added the last route (root :to => 'users#show'

Stackoverflow community is great.  I have been getting a lot of help from the archives.

Comment: It's odd you have a duplicated `get` directive in there. Normally if you generate a controller you should do `resources :users`.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're seeing is because of the following line:

get 'controller_name/[actions]'

Say you want to route `GET localhost:3000/welcome` to `PagesController#welcome`. You'd need specify both the path and the controller#action in your routes:

```
get '/welcome', controller: 'pages#index'
```

I'd really recommend you read up on routing! [Rails has a great guide on routing.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Aside from that, you have a few other errors in your code. Here's an annotated version:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # These two routes are invalid
  get 'controller_name/[actions]'
  get 'controller_name/[options]'

  # This routes the root of your site (localhost:3000/) 
  # to ArticlesController#index
  # 
  # This should be moved to the top of the file
  root :to => "articles#index"
  resources :articles

  # You can't have two root routes!
  root :to => 'users#show'
end
```

Good luck, and welcome to Rails!